# I want Sqoop data from SQL Server database to hive table

Tags: sql, sql-server, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I want to Sqoop data from a SQL Server database to a hive table and some entries are of the form `9.653133E+08`. I want to have this entry in exactly the same way in hive table as it's in source. As is, what I have in hive table when I try to sqoop from SQL Server is `965313340` and it seems it's being converted sort of. I don't want it converted at all and I want it in hive exactly like in this form (`9.653133E+08`) as it's in the SQL Server database. How can I achieve this please?

Comment: I can only assume you mean you are getting 965313300 as that is the actual number. Not sure what you mean by how you have it stored in sql server. What datatype are you using in sql server?

Comment: In short, it's not being converted. It is stored as the number 965313300 in your sql server table. The only conversion happening here is in your client when you query the database/view the data. I'm assuming excel? It would be a REALLY bad idea to store a number as text with scientific notation. You would be rendering the number useless storing it in such a manner.

Comment: @SeanLange ... I want to sqoop the data from Sql Server table to a Hive table. At the moment, the enrties in the rows of the Sql Server table is of the form 9.653133E+08 and after sqooping to Hive, I have something like 965313340 but I actually want t have the exact same data  (9.653133E+08) from source in my hive table and not a conversion.. What I'm trying to achieve is to obtain the exact same data in the hive table after sqooping it to hive.. How can this be achieved? What kind of data type do I need to give the columns to retain this exact data  (9.653133E+08) in hive?

Comment: @JNevil ... I want to sqoop the data from Sql Server table to a Hive table. At the moment, the enrties in the rows of the Sql Server table is of the form 9.653133E+08 and after sqooping to Hive, I have something like 965313340 but I actually want t have the exact same data  (9.653133E+08) from source in my hive table and not a conversion.. What I'm trying to achieve is to obtain the exact same data in the hive table after sqooping it to hive.. How can this be achieved? What kind of data type do I need to give the columns to retain this exact data  (9.653133E+08) in hive?

Comment: Again...what datatype are you using in sql server?

Comment: Hi @SeanLange ... The datatype in Sql server table is real.

Comment: So you realize that the scientific notation you are seeing is a display property right? The actual value stored is 965313300. But if you are concerned about accuracy you should not be using the real datatype because it is not an exact datatype. In fact, it is just a synonym for float. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Here try this so you can see what I mean. select convert(real, 965313300)

Comment: Just to reiterate the number being stored in your database to your hard drive is literally `965313340`. The only reason you are seeing it as `9.653133E+08` is because the software you are using to query your database and display what it's storing is converting it to make it prettier for us humans. So what you are asking is how do I convert this literal `965313340` to scientific notation and then store that in my hive table. I really question if that is a good idea though. Why take good data like `965313340` and willingly lose data AND functionality by converting it to `9.653133E+08`

Comment: Thanks so much @SeanLange ... That's right. select convert(real, 965313300) gave back the scientific notation which shows that it's infact the display property. That was really helpful. Really appreciate.

Comment: Yes @JNevill ... I now understand what's going on under the hood and I very much agree with your explanation. Thanks so much.